# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Date out of START_ARRAY token for static attribute

Tags: java, json, annotations

How can I avoid this exception even after using `JsonSubTypes`?

I'll not get the exception if I remove static concept.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@type", visible=true)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Date.class, name = "date")})
```

```java
public **static** Date time;
```

JSON format used is
`" time ": [" date ", " 2016 -12 -31 T12 :00:00.000+0000 "]`

Comment: You should provide more code and more stack trace of the exception.